# Geometry problem only needed hint one more

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

[image]

I just want hint how to use the congruent condition..which involves an equation in X I guess

And I obtained one equation
$$y^2=x (16+x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $AC\simeq BC$ tells you that $\angle ABF=\angle BCD$. So, $ABF$ and $DCF$ are similar triangles. You get another equation from here.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @learningstudent You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\measuredangle BCD=\measuredangle CAB=\measuredangle B,$$ we obtain $$AB||CD$$ and from here we have the following system:
$$y^2=x(x+16)$$ and
$$\frac{y}{3}=\frac{x+10}{6}.$$
I got $$x=2.$$